# How to get the only the files committed in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I have my git repository and it has the following structure.

```
domains/
    test.txt
.gitlab-ci.yml
```

And this `test.txt` under `domains/` contains following content:

```
abc.com
cde.com
efg.com
```

What I want to do this, if I add another entry to that `test.txt` file as `xyz.com`, it would look like this:

```
abc.com
cde.com
efg.com
xyz.com
```

So, I commited this change to `master`, now what I want is, I need to get this commit and any changes made with that commit and extract only the changes I did to the file inside `domains/` directory and echo that in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
 - build

build:
 stage: build
 script: 
  - echo "<echo-only-the-changed-lines-in-domain/text.txt>"
```

How can I do this with `gitlab` variables or any other way?

Comment: something along `git diff (or git show) $CI_COMMIT_SHA domains/test.txt`? How would you do it outside of gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

There's no predefined variable or other method to get the changed files (or their content), but you can retrieve the info from git with help from a variable.

The `$CI_COMMIT_SHA` variable holds the full commit sha for the commit the pipeline is running on, regardless if it's from a branch or tag. You can use this with the git command `show` along with an option to list all files that were changed in this commit, along with their status (modified only, added, or deleted):

```
git show $CI_COMMIT_SHA --name-status > output
```

The `--name-status` option tells the `show` command to only give us the name of the changed files as well as their status (modified, added, deleted) and now the full diff. We redirect the output of the command to a file because otherwise it's automatically piped through something like `less` that hangs your terminal until it's closed. Redirecting the output is required for a CI/CD environment where you can't close the file.

The file will contain something like this:

```
commit HASH
Author: author
Date: date

    Commit Message

M file1.txt
M file2.txt
D file3.png
A file4.jiffy
```

This has what we need, but also other content we don't, but we can get rid of it with grep and a regex:

```
git show $CI_COMMIT_SHA --name-status | grep "^[AM]\s.*"
```

Explaining exactly what the regex does is a little out of scope for this issue, but you can copy/paste it into regex101.com and it will give you a description of each component. The important part is the `[AM]`. We don't include the `D` for deleted files in here because for our context, we don't care about deleted files. The results of this command will show something like:

```
M file1.txt
M file2.txt
A file4.jiffy
```

without the sha, author, date, commit message, or deleted files. From here we can treat Added or Modified the same, so we can lost the status character:

```
git show $CI_COMMIT_SHA --name-status | grep "^[AM]\s.*" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Understanding awk is a college course in itself, but just know that the syntax above splits whatever is sent to awk into columns, then prints only the second column to get out list of filenames:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file4.jiffy
```

Once you have that, you could loop through each filename, `cat` it to get the contents, then continue with whatever else you need to do!

Comment: Thank you very much. This is good, but I actually need the lines that has been added or modified in those files added or modified. I actually need the content. How can I do that? And again, thank you for your answer, this is more than helpful. Any idea on getting the changed content within that file?

Comment: Do you need the content of the files after the changes were made, or to see what the changes were? My answer above shows the files after they're changed, but you can just run `git show $CI_COMMIT_SHA` to view the full diff showing each line that was added, removed, etc., though it would be more difficult to use it programmatically.

Comment: Yes I want to see the content of the files that has changed. From your method we can get the files that has changed, from there onwards, can I see what lines or content has been changed in those files?

Comment: Only by viewing the full diff with `git show $CI_COMMIT_SHA`